# Path to node modules in webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

I have a project consisting of several apps and want to be able to build the complete project using a global webpack.config.js, with webpack 3.0 (which works). At the same time, I want to have local webpack.config.js files to build each project seperately. The project structure is as follows:

```
- src
  - project_1
    ...
    webpack.config.js
  ...
  - project_n
    ...
    webpack.config.js
  ...
  node_modules
  webpack.config.js
```

Obviously, I don't want to copy the node_modules in the project subfolders. How can I reference the global node_modules folder from the webpack.config.js of a project subfolder?

I tried

```
resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname,'../node_modules')]
},
```

in one of the subfolder webpack configs but I get many errors of the type

> error TS2304: Cannot find name [...]

because apparently node_modules cannot be located.

Here is my complete webpack.config.js for project_1:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require("path")

module.exports =  {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/project_1.ts"),
    output: {
        filename: "project_1_bundle.js",
        path:  path.resolve(__dirname, "bin")
    },
    externals: [
        "angular",
        "uuid",
        {
            "lodash": {
                commonjs: "lodash",
                amd: "lodash",
                root: "_" // indicates global variable
            }
        },
        {
            "jquery": {
                root: "$",
                amd: "jquery",
                commonjs: 'jquery'
            }
        },
        {
            "jquery-ui": {
                amd: "jquery-ui",
                commonjs: 'jquery-ui'
            }
        },
        {
            "Slick": {
                root: "Slick",
                amd: "Slick",
                commonjs: 'Slick'
            }
        }
    ],
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
    // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
    extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname,'../node_modules')]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: ['tslint-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: ['ts-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ['html-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: See this https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules

Comment: I tried that without success (see updated op).

Comment: share the part of your webpack config, which version of webpack are you using?

Comment: This is the docs for webpack 1 http://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html#resolving-a-module-path

Comment: @CallumLinington I am using webpack 3.

Comment: So, I'm not seeing the place where you added `resolve: { modules: '../node_modules' }`

Comment: I have added the complete config to the original post. See updated version.

Comment: You haven't added what I suggested? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules

Comment: Just did, @CallumLinington - see updated original post.

Comment: Try using path.resolve to get the absolute path

Comment: @CallumLinington Just did, see original post. But I get the same error. Could there be a problem with typescript, which I use in this project?